# unnumbered special headers in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, reproducible-research

I'm writing my thesis with in Rmarkdown (and I will export it to PDF).

My  third chapter should include three unnumbered parts (or some sort of special header) because it makes sense thematically. 
Is there any way to include them but not as regular headers? because if in TOC the limit of depth is 3, I would lose important subheaders.

Comment: Shall they be actual headers but only not numbered or do you just want them to look like headers but not be in the TOC? Perhaps there's some way to define a CSS class for them?

Comment: actual headers not numbered just in that chapter, I would like them to be if possible in the TOC

Comment: Please check the duplicate and in case it doesn't answer your question, post a new one. Also check http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#headers

Comment: I've read that link, but it makes sense for an appendix at the end of the document, if you unnumber for example ,chapter 4, all headings and subheadings  are numbered as chapter 3's